# Python Quicksort Recursion unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'`

Tags: python, function, sorting, call

I have been having issues with a sorting program I am writing, the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Shaun/PycharmProjects/Sorts/BubbleSort.py", line 117, in <module>
    sorted = quick_sort(unsorted, 0, len(unsorted - 1))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'
```

occurs at the function call for my quicksort see below

```
print("You chose Quick Sort\n")
sorted = []
sorted = quick_sort(unsorted, 0, len(unsorted - 1))
```

Here is the quicksort function with its input parameters

```
def quick_sort(list, leftBound, rightBound) -> object:

    leftBound = int(leftBound)
    rightBound = int(rightBound)
    pivot = int((list[math.floor(leftBound + rightBound / 2)]))
    print(pivot)
    while leftBound <= rightBound:

        # while bigger numbers are above pivot and lower are below
        # update bounds left + , right -
        while list[leftBound] < pivot:
            leftBound += 1
        while list[rightBound] > pivot:
            rightBound -= 1

        if (leftBound <= rightBound):
            list[rightBound], list[leftBound] = list[leftBound], list[rightBound]
            leftBound += 1
            rightBound -= 1
    if (leftBound < rightBound):
         quick_sort(list, leftBound, rightBound)
    if (rightBound < leftBound):
        quick_sort(list, leftBound, rightBound)

    print(list)
    return list
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is clearly stated in the Error message:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'
```

It means you are doing an operation, which is "-" (as stated in the error message: "for -") on operands whose type(s) not supported by this Operation.

So you were subtracting an INT type from a LIST type.

you need to change that line from:

```
len(unsorted - 1)
```

to

```
len(unsorted) - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
len(unsorted - 1)
```

should be

```
len(unsorted) - 1
```